# how to get basic files

Tags: software-installation

I don't have `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppaany` file available in the volume space of ubuntu. I want to install wine in ubuntu 14.04 but the error is occurring when I typed a command.

The command `sudo apt-get install wine` also gives me the same error as "unable to locate package wine".

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install wine1.6 winetricks
```

wine1.6 is still installable in Ubuntu 20.04, but in Ubuntu 18.04 and later wine-stable is a newer version than wine1.6 and in Ubuntu 16.04 and later wine-development is an even newer version than wine-stable.

If you want to install Wine 1.7 from the [Wine Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) in 14.04 instead of Wine 1.6 run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Wine 1.7 (wine1.7) from the Wine Team PPA was updated a few days ago.

winetricks (optional) is a shell script that can be used to download and install various redistributable libraries that may be needed for some programs to work in Wine.